# When a file of size > 50 MB arrived at sftp server copy into Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

Whenever file gets added into sftp server I have to copy into Azure blob storage. The logic app works only for file size upto 50MB. How to copy the new files of size >50MB copied from sftp server to Azure Storage.The sftp connection doesnt have ssh properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFTP-SSH actions that support chunking can handle files up to 1 GB, while SFTP-SSH actions that don't support chunking can handle files up to 50 MB. Although the default chunk size is 15 MB, this size can dynamically change, starting from 5 MB and gradually increasing to the 50 MB maximum, based on factors such as network latency, server response time, and so on.

By default, Azure Blob Storage actions can read or write files that are 50 MB or smaller. To handle files larger than 50 MB but up to 1024 MB, Azure Blob Storage actions support message chunking. The Get blob content action implicitly uses chunking.

It is just that SFTP-SSH and Azure blob storage 'triggers' won't support files more than 50MB. But you can use 'when files are added or modified (properties only)' trigger to get the metadata and use 'get file content' action with chunking to fetch files up to 1 GB

[image]